# Erro ao atualizar o Java

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Apareceu uma notificação padrão dizendo que havia uma nova atualização do Java disponível, então resolvi atualizar. Depois da atualização não consigo rodar meus aplicativos no Eclipse e aparece a seguinte mensagem:

[image: Mensagem de Erro]

Imports:

**Classe Cadastrar**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;
```

**Classe Principal**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
```

Eu estava procurando nas bibliotecas no Java Build Path quando achei a biblioteca nativa do Android (Native library location) vazia e as anotações externas (External annotations). Seria isso um problema?

[image: Java Build Path]

**Bibliotecas**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Mensagem de erro no log**
[Erro no log](https://gist.github.com/MarcosPauloSR/2d2f7abc7610083fcfaac0cb87b5f9e9#file-erro-ao-atualizar-o-java) Eu tive que colocar no GitHub porque não coube aqui

Comment: Qual versão do eclipse você está executando?

Comment: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/master/sdklib/src/main/java/com/android/sdklib/internal/build/SignedJarBuilder.java#177

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47216694/540552

Comment: Estou usando o Eclipse Oxygen e eu tinha achado esse tópico antes de fazer esta pergunta, e não consegui entender quase nada, por isso eu fiz essa pergunta

Comment: E quanto ao link, o que devo fazer com ele?

Comment: Se você instalar o Eclipse Photon, funciona?

Comment: Nunca usei esta versão, mas tentarei

Comment: Não estou dizendo que é para fazer algo quanto ao link. Só estou apontando coisas que achei que são relevantes até para ajudar outras pessoas que vejam a sua pergunta poderem talvez respondê-la.

Comment: @VictorStafusa eu acabei de instalar o Eclipse Photon e instalei o ADT Plugin mas mesmo assim continua dando o mesmo erro. =(

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger coloquei o link acima.

Answer (score 3):

Em algum lugar do seu projeto `CadastroDeProdutos` deve haver isso:

```
import sun.misc.BASE64Encoder;
```

Por exemplo, vamos compilar essa classe abaixo:

```
import sun.misc.BASE64Encoder;
public class Teste {}
```

Ao fazer isso, o compilador do Java até a versão 8 imediatamente te dá uma *warning*:

> ```
> Teste.java:1: warning: BASE64Encoder is internal proprietary API and may be removed in a future release
> import sun.misc.BASE64Encoder;
>                ^
> ```

Traduzindo:

> BASE64Encoder é uma API interna proprietária e pode ser removida em uma versão futura

Esse aviso não deveria ser ignorado. As classes começando com `sun.` são internas da JDK e não deveriam **NUNCA** ser utilizadas diretamente. Por tal motivo, não há qualquer garantia quanto a estabilidade ou disponibilidade delas. Qualquer projeto que as utilize corre o risco de não ser portável.

Ou seja, na verdade o seu projeto esteve sempre errado desde o início devido ao fato dele utilizar uma classe que nunca deveria ter sido utilizada e compilava graças a uma falha na arquitetura da linguagem.

O aviso afirma que essa classe poderia ser removida em uma versão futura, e eis que um dia essa versão futura chegou! A partir do Java 9, os mecanismos adequados para esconder classes que não deveriam ser visíveis foram adicionados como parte do conceito de módulos. No entanto, a classe `sun.misc.BASE64Encoder` não foi apenas escondida. Ela foi de fato removida por completo de dentro da JDK.

No entanto, há uma solução simples para esse problema. A partir do Java 8, a classe [`java.util.Base64.Encoder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Base64.Encoder.html) foi adicionada. Logo, não há mais porque usar a `sun.misc.BASE64Encoder`. Entretanto, as APIs das duas classes têm algumas diferenças, embora não deva haver nada muito difícil de se migrar.

Pode até ser que você esteja usando uma biblioteca XPTO qualquer feita por terceiros e que essa biblioteca esteja usando o `sun.misc.BASE64Encoder`. Nesse caso a situação é um pouco mais complicada, porque aí é a biblioteca que está errada. Esse tipo de situação gerou algum rebuliço e muita gente achou ruim por causa dessas falhas inesperadas. Mas aí, voltamos ao que a *warning* relata, que essas classes não deveriam ser usadas diretamente, e portanto, o azar é de quem o fez ou confiou na biblioteca de alguém que fez isso.

Moral da história: Nunca use qualquer classe que comece com `sun.`. Não é a toa que elas tem um aviso bem grande dizendo que não devem ser utilizadas.

Comment: No meu código não existe nenhum import que comece com `sun` ou que tenha no seu corpo. Irei disponibilizar os imports

Comment: @MarcosPauloS.Rezende pode haver chamada direta, sem precisar da importação, como `sun.misc.BASE64Encoder`

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado esse é o grande problema, porque não encontrei em meu código nenhuma chamada com `sun` ou `misc`

Comment: @MarcosPauloS.Rezende Que bibliotecas você está usando?

Comment: Irei colocar acima

Answer (score 3):

Esta não é a resposta que eu gostaria de postar, mas vamos lá:

Primeiro, achei mais gente relatando esse bug ou no mínimo algo muito parecido:

- https://stackoverflow.com/q/47216694/540552
- http://www.androidiani.com/forum/iniziare-programmare-android/542624-problema-sun-misc-base64encoder.html
- https://www.concretepage.com/questions/585

Como eu disse [na minha outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/316850/132), a classe `sun.misc.BASE64Encoder` foi removida do Java 9 e na verdade nunca deveria ter sido visível.

O Eclipse usa um plugin chamado ADT, desenvolvido pelo Google, para o desenvolvimento Android. Nas profundezas do código do ADT, a classe `sun.misc.BASE64Encoder` é utilizada por uma classe chamada `SignedJarBuilder` que está com um `@Deprecated` [(fonte)](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/15b87e04903a0f3cc1200729e26891d43f8a9cbe/sdklib/src/main/java/com/android/sdklib/internal/build/SignedJarBuilder.java#177).

Entretanto, o desenvolvimento do ADT foi abandonado pelo Google em 2015 ([1](https://developer.android.com/studio/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt) e [2](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2015/06/an-update-on-eclipse-android-developer.html)). A motivação foi porque o ADT está cheio de bugs e falhas de segurança e porque o Google quer forçar todo mundo a migrar para o Android Studio.

Assim sendo, as únicas soluções existentes são todas dolorosas:

- Executar o Eclipse no Java 8. Tanto o Eclipse Oxygen quanto o Eclipse Photon necessitam do Java 8 no mínimo, então isso deve funcionar. Quando sair alguma futura versão do Eclipse que tenha como requisito mínimo, algum Java ≥ 9, isso não vai mais ser possível.
- Migrar para o Android Studio. Ou talvez para o Netbeans ou alguma outra coisa.
- Fazer um fork do ADT e corrigir esse e quaisquer outros bugs similares que venham a surgir. Provavelmente, isso é trabalhoso demais para valer a pena.

Comment: Infelizmente parece que vou ter que migrar para o Android Studio =(